# Using different sftp session factories

Tags: spring-boot, sftp, spring-integration-sftp

Currently i upload all my generated files to single **SFTP** and all works perfectly. But requirements are changed and i need to upload file on different **SFTP** server.
Example:
On REST endpoint i got request `type=FULL`, then i need to upload file to **SFTP1**, if `type=PART`, then i need to upload to **SFTP2**.

My sftp config:

```
  @Bean
  public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
    final DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    factory.setHost(properties.getHost());
    factory.setPort(properties.getPort());
    factory.setUser(properties.getUser());
    factory.setPassword(properties.getPassword());
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
  public MessageHandler handler(@Value("'${sftp.folder}'.concat(headers['type'])")
                                  final String remoteDirectory) {
    final SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
    handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpressionString(remoteDirectory);
    handler.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
    return handler;
  }

@MessagingGateway
public interface SftpService {

  @Gateway(requestChannel = "toSftpChannel")
  void uploadFileToSftp(@Payload File file,
                        @Header("filename") String filename,
                        @Header("type") String type);
}
```

Is it possible to create 2 session factories and use them on some conditions?

Also, if i will have different logic for directories on first and second **SFTP** servers, do i need two `SftpMessageHandlers` and `MessagingGateways`?

Now i think as solution to create two `SftpService` interfaces, two packs of configs and in application logic change where to upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by creating second

```
@Bean
  public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
    final DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    factory.setHost(properties.getHost());
    factory.setPort(properties.getPort());
    factory.setUser(properties.getUser());
    factory.setPassword(properties.getPassword());
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    return factory;
  }
```

For second sftp connection, and implemented second

```
@Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
  public MessageHandler handler(@Value("'${sftp.folder}'.concat(headers['type'])")
                                  final String remoteDirectory) {
    final SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
    handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpressionString(remoteDirectory);
    handler.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
    return handler;
  }

@MessagingGateway
public interface SftpService {

  @Gateway(requestChannel = "toSftpChannel")
  void uploadFileToSftp(@Payload File file,
                        @Header("filename") String filename,
                        @Header("type") String type);
}
```

with different `inputChannel` name